# background-position:centre centre; in css tricks video not understanding on hover

Tags: css

i am watching this css video at http://www.youtube.com/user/realcsstricks#p/u/10/HJLp-M3-WOs at 15:15 chris writes code like this

```
ul#nav li a:hover
{
 background-position:centre centre; 
}
```

after that code tabs changes color on hovers how this is possible i am not understanding him. Thanks for help.

Comment: It's the American spelling, "center", by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property aligns the `background-image` to the exact center of the element upon `:hover`:

```
background-position: center center;
```

Earlier on in the code, the `background-image` was probably positioned differently:

```
ul#nav li a:hover
{
 background-position: center top; 
}
```

The background image is probably a sprite (Google the term):

[image]

Positioning the background will allow you to crop out a small section of a large image (preserves bandwidth and loading time goes down).

Comment: please can you make a little fiddle to demonstrate it. Thanks

Comment: Google has what you need. Google: **CSS sprites**.

Answer (score 0):

Read something about [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/) and you will understand!

Basically you create an one image with two states. On your page you show only a part of that image (only 1 state). The image is set as a background. With changing the position of the background-image, you change it's state and voila!

With two states I mean something like [this](http://www.webdesigntoolcase.com/images/php-automate-creation-of-images-for-css-sprites_ftssf_0.jpg). You can see the upper and the lower state which you change with the positioning.

Comment: please can you make a little fiddle to demonstrate it.Thanks